# Write byte strings to a file

Tags: lxml

I have following code

```
from lxml import etree
xmlns = "http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/confirmation"
xsi  = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
fpmlVersion="http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/confirmation ../../fpml-main-5-6.xsd http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig# ../../xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"
page = etree.Element("{"+xmlns+"}dataDocument",nsmap={None:xmlns,'xsi':xsi })
doc = etree.ElementTree(page)
page.set("fpmlVersion", fpmlVersion)
trade = etree.SubElement(page,'trade')
party = etree.SubElement(page,'party',id='party1')
partyID = etree.SubElement(party,'partyID')
partyID.text = 'PARTYAUS33'
partyName = etree.SubElement(party,'partyName')
partyName.text = 'Party A'
party = etree.SubElement(page,'party',id='party2')
partyID = etree.SubElement(party,'partyID')
partyID.text = 'BARCGB2L'
partyName = etree.SubElement(party,'partyName')
partyName.text = 'Party B'
s = etree.tostring(doc, xml_declaration=True,encoding="UTF-8",pretty_print=True)
print (s)
```

How do i save the contents of S to a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `open()` a new file in binary mode, and later use the filehandle `write()` function, so add:

```
import sys
fd = open(sys.argv[1], 'wb')
```

at the beginning.

And:

```
fd.write(s)
```

at the end.

So, you now have to pass an additional argument to the script, that will be the output file to write. Also note that I use the `w` flag in the `open()` function that will destroy (to re-create) any file with that name in current directory.

Run it like:

```
python3 script.py outfile
```

That yields:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<dataDocument xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/confirmation" fpmlVersion="http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/confirmation ../../fpml-main-5-6.xsd http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig# ../../xmldsig-core-schema.xsd">
  <trade/>
  <party id="party1">
    <partyID>PARTYAUS33</partyID>
    <partyName>Party A</partyName>
  </party>
  <party id="party2">
    <partyID>BARCGB2L</partyID>
    <partyName>Party B</partyName>
  </party>
</dataDocument>
```

Comment: Birei Thanks again for helping me twice in a row :)